# Configuring FTP on Ubuntu 12.04 Amazon EC2 that works with Interarchy

Tags: ftp, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I've read through every forum post about configuring my ftp correctly. I'll go through my steps below. Please let me know where I'm going wrong!

1. Get vsftpd (sudo apt-get install vsftpd)
2. modify vsftpd.conf to enable listening, writing, local user. Disable anonymous user.
3. Add ports in vsftpd.conf (I did 1028-1048 as per another post I read)
4. Assign passive IP address using elastic IP.
5. In AWS portal, add security inbound ports for 20-21 and 1028-1048.
6. Make a new user profile and give it a password.
7. Restart vsftpd.

Then I try and login using interarchy, and it still doesn't work. I'm losing my mind over this. Please help.